# Change Character Allowance

Tags: oracle

I have a `VARCHAR` field that only allows 12 characters max. How do I change character allowance to 9 or 15 for example?

Google succeeds in telling me what the max number of characters in `VARCHAR` in any given version of Oracle database. I know, I get that. I just want to `ALTER` the column character allowance within that range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alter table table_name MODIFY (column_to_change varchar(new size))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name MODIFY col_name column_definition;
```

So if you have:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  value VARCHAR2(12)
);
```

Then you can do:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY value VARCHAR2(15 BYTE);
```

and the column will have a capacity of `15` bytes.

Or:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY value VARCHAR2(9 CHAR);
```

and the column will have a capacity of `9` characters.